# Monty Hall problem in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation

Some years ago I made a Monty Hall simulations in Java, and now I decided to give it a go in Python, after learning (yet another) the language at university.

I decided to make a generalized, object-oriented and modularized version of the game, in order to see what alterations would impact the results; and to get more comfortable with Object-Oriented code.

I mainly have two questions, although all tips, ideas and hints are welcome:

1) Would I benefit from making `Player` a subclass of Game (or the other way around)?

2) How would I best analyze the results from my code? I thought about initializing the variables with a `numpy` range, but I'm not used to working with it. I could then print the results on a graph with `mathplotlib`, I guess.

```
import random

NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 10000
P_SWAP = False
P_CAN_SELECT_SAME = False
N_DOORS = 5
N_PRIZES = 3
N_PLAYERS = 1

VERBOSE = True
PRINT_CANDY = "="*64+"\n"

try:
    assert isinstance(P_SWAP, bool)
    assert N_DOORS > 0
    assert N_PRIZES > 0
    assert N_PLAYERS >= 0
    assert isinstance(VERBOSE, bool)
except (AssertionError, TypeError):
    print("Invalid value for initialisation values")
    exit()

try:
    assert N_PRIZES <= N_DOORS
except AssertionError:
    print("Can't have more prizes than doors")
    exit()

try:
    assert N_PLAYERS < N_DOORS - N_PRIZES
except AssertionError:
    print("Must have at least 2 less players than doors")
    exit()


GIFT = ["CAR"]
COAL = ["GOAT", "POOP", "COAL", "CRAP"]

win_counter = 0
lose_counter = 0


# overriding print functions
def supress_prints():
    """
    Since print() redirects strings to STDOUT, we can override
    this to /dev/null, instead of terminal, and thus
    avoid printing unnecessary information. Speeds up program too.
    """
    import sys, os
    if VERBOSE:
        return
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
def restore_prints():
    """
    Returns print() to its default value: STDOUT.
    """
    import sys
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


class Door:
    def __init__(self, game: "Game", content: str, is_open: bool=False):
        self.content = content
        self.is_open = is_open
        self.index = len(game.doors)  # works as long as no doors are deleted from the game
        print(self)

    def is_prize(self):
        if self.content == GIFT:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_open(self):
        return self.is_open

    def is_closed(self):
        return not self.is_open

    def open(self):
        self.is_open = True

    def close(self):
        self.is_open = False

    def __str__(self):
        return ["Open " if self.is_open else "Closed "][0] + self.content + " @door " + str(self.index)


class Game:
    def __init__(self, 
                swaps: bool=True,
                number_of_doors: int=3,
                number_of_prizes: int=1,
                number_of_players: int=1,
                players_can_collide: bool=False
        )->"Game":

        self.number_of_doors = number_of_doors
        self.number_of_prizes = number_of_prizes
        self.number_of_players = number_of_players
        self.players_can_collide = players_can_collide

        self.doors = list()
        self.prizes = list()
        self.open_doors = list()

        # create a Player object for each allowed player in the game
        print("Creating players...")
        self.players = list()
        while len(self.players) < number_of_players:
            self.players.append(
                Player(self, swaps)
            )
        print("Done!"); print()

        # figure out what doors should contain each prize
        while len(self.prizes) < number_of_prizes:
            self.winning_door = None
            while self.winning_door in self.prizes \
                or self.winning_door == None:
                    self.winning_door = random.randrange(0,number_of_doors)

            self.prizes.append(self.winning_door)


        # create all the Door objects in the game, while adding
        # their contents simultaneously
        print("Creating doors...")
        for new_door in range(number_of_doors):
            if new_door in self.prizes:
                self.doors.append(
                    Door(self, random.choice(GIFT))
                )
            else:
                self.doors.append(
                    Door(self, random.choice(COAL))
                )
        print("Done!"); 

        print("Game is configured!")
        print(PRINT_CANDY)


    def start_game(self):
        #############
        # round one #
        #############

        print("ROUND ONE: \n")

        # let all players select a door
        self.selected_doors = list()
        for player in self.players:
            selection = player.select_door()

        # finding doors which can be opened: must not be selected, nor can't have a GIFT in it
        self.removable_candidates = list()
        for player in self.players:
            for door in self.doors:
                if door.is_closed():
                    if self.doors.index(door) not in self.selected_doors:
                        if door.content not in GIFT:
                            self.removable_candidates.append(door) 


        # clear selections for game state (still saved in Player instances)
        self.selected_doors.clear()

        print(PRINT_CANDY)

        ####
        ## TODO: maybe add some temporary stat printing here
        #### 


        #############
        # round two #
        #############

        print("ROUND TWO: \n")
        self.pandora_door = random.choice(self.removable_candidates)  # a door with evil stuff in it
        self.pandora_door.open()
        print("Pandora door:", self.pandora_door)
        self.open_doors.append(self.pandora_door)  # open one COAL door

        print()

        # for all players that want to swap door, do so now
        for player in self.players:
            if player.swaps:
                player.select_door(force_change=True)
        print()


        ###############
        # end of game #
        ###############

        # print results
        print("Final results!")
        for player in self.players:
            global win_counter, lose_counter
            print("Player", player.index, end=": ")
            if self.doors[player.selection].content in GIFT:
                print("Won a", self.doors[player.selection].content, "at door", player.selection)
                win_counter += 1
            else:
                print("Got some", self.doors[player.selection].content, "by selecting door", player.selection)
                lose_counter += 1



class Player:
    def __init__(self, game: Game, swaps: bool) -> "Player":

        self.game = game  # could possibly be called by with super(), defining Player as a subclass of Game
        self.swaps = swaps

        self.selection = None
        self.index = len(game.players)  # non-intuitive, but works as long as players are not removed from game
        print("Created player", self.index)

    def select_door(self, force_change: int=False) -> int:
        """
        Allow player to choose any Door from the game which
        is not opened, and depending on the settings, whether is not 
        already selected by another player.
        """


        self.old_selection = self.selection
        self.selection = None

        while (self.selection in self.game.selected_doors and self.game.players_can_collide) \
            or self.selection in self.game.open_doors \
            or (self.selection == self.old_selection and force_change) \
            or self.selection is None:
                self.selection = random.randrange(0, self.game.number_of_doors)
                self.game.selected_doors.append(self.selection)         

        print("Player", self.index, "selected door", self.selection)
        return self.selection  # helper, not required


supress_prints()

for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_GAMES):
    Monty_Hall_Game = Game(swaps=P_SWAP, number_of_doors=N_DOORS, number_of_prizes=N_PRIZES, number_of_players=N_PLAYERS)
    Monty_Hall_Game.start_game()
    print(PRINT_CANDY*2)

print()
restore_prints()

win_percent = win_counter*100//(NUMBER_OF_GAMES*N_PLAYERS)
lose_percent = lose_counter*100//(NUMBER_OF_GAMES*N_PLAYERS)

print(f"""
Statistics:
{PRINT_CANDY}
With a total of {NUMBER_OF_GAMES} games, configured as:
Players: {N_PLAYERS}
Swapping: {P_SWAP}
Colliding: {P_CAN_SELECT_SAME}

Doors: {N_DOORS}
Prizes: {N_PRIZES}

{win_counter} wins \t ({win_percent}%),
{lose_counter} losses \t ({lose_percent}%)!

{PRINT_CANDY}""")
```

All in all, how can I improve my code? What makes you cringe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ve got many errors in your code.

In `class Door`, you set `self.is_open` to `False`, but door already contained the method `def is_open(self)`, so you’ve overwritten the object’s method, and can no longer call `door.is_open()`.

The method `def is_open(self)` returned `self.is_open`, which would be a method reference if it wasn’t overwritten above, so the method would have always return a “truthy” value.

In `class Player`, you have `def select_door(self, force_change: int=False)`.  The parameter `force_change` is given the type `int`, with a default value of `False`.  Round peg in a square hole.

---

Your code is unnecessarily verbose:

```
    if self.content == GIFT:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Could be:

```
    return self.content == GIFT
```

But `GIFT` is a list of all of the prizes!  Shouldn’t there just be one prize behind a door?  Maybe:

```
    return self.content in GIFT
```

How does your code actually work?  Oh, right, you never call the method `door.is_prize()`, just like you never call `door.is_open()`.  If you write a function, test it and make sure it works.

---

> 1) Would I benefit from making Player a subclass of Game (or the other
>   way around)?

Use the “is-a” test.  Is a player a game?  I’d say “no”.  How about is a game a player?  Again, I’d say “no”.  Unless the answer to one of those is a “yes”, making something a subclass of another thing is a very bad idea.